# reading a file into an Arraylist but argument lists differ in length

Tags: java, arraylist, file-io

I'm stuck on a question of fileIO. Basically, there is a class called Student and there is a method called readStudent and it will return an ArrayList object.

I was asked to read a file and split them into 3 parts by single space,
and not allowed to use Scanner.

the file:

Amy Moore 60

Chloe Scott 40

My questions are, (1) since the Student class only has two parameters(String, Double), how can I add two Strings and one Double into Student? (2) the Student class provided has no toString() method, how can I print it out?

I would greatly appreciated if anyone can help me.

the constructor of Student is like:

```
 public Student(String sstudent, double mmark)
```

the readStudent:

```
 public static ArrayList<Student> readStudent(String fName){
```

What I have done so far:

```
 ArrayList<Student> list=new ArrayList<Student>();
 try{

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fName));

     String line;

     while((line=br.readLine())!=null){


        String[] splitLine=line.split(" ");
        String first=splitLine[0];
        String second=splitLine[1];
        Double third=Double.parseDouble(splitLine[3]);

       Student stu=
            new Student(first,second));


        list.add(stu);


    }

  ...... 

  return list;
```

}

Comment: `Student stu = new Student(first + " " + second, third);`  OR `Student stu = new Student(splitLine[0] + " " + splitLine[1], splitLine[2]);`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Thanks a lot!  what a simple answer, but I never thought of it in that way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your problem (1)

```
Student s = new Student(first + " " + second, third);
//by the way for third,it is not splitLine[3],it is splitLine[2]
```

For your problem (2)

```
ArrayList<Student> studentList = readStudent("YourFileName");
for(Student s : studentList)
    System.out.println(s.name + " " + s.grade);//don't know what are the variable names of Student class instances
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You  have different choices in code:
//Problem 1(see above first comment):
If you do not need first, second and third for any reason, go for option 1 (It's efficient).

```
public static ArrayList<Student> readStudent(String fName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

        ArrayList<Student> list=new ArrayList<Student>();
        //try{

        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fName));

        String line;

        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){

            //option1
            String[] splitLine=line.split(" ");
            Student stu = new Student(splitLine[0] + " " + splitLine[1], splitLine[2]);

            //option2
//            String first=splitLine[0];
//            String second=splitLine[1];
//            double third=Double.parseDouble(splitLine[3]);            
//            Student stu = new Student(first + " " + second, third); 


            list.add(stu);


        }

        //......

        return list;
    }
```

//Problem 2:
In java getter and setter are used to access attribute of a class (it's a preferred style). Check if there is some in class student then use it.
In option 2 , you can access direction global variable of student object.

```
printStudents(readStudent("your file name"));     //print a list of student objects 

void printStudents(List<Student> students){
    for(Student stu: students)
        //option 1: using getter
        System.out.println(stu.getSStudent()+"  "+stu.getMark());

        //option 2: accessing attributes 
        //System.out.println(stu.sstudent+"  "+stu.mark);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help and for providing me an alternative, but those given Student attributes are private.

Comment: @MidoriXie welcome. So use getter to access it and please mark my answer as  useful, if it helps you